# how to use output binding without having to assign a value?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

**How do I specify output bindings without being forced to assign a value to them?**

I am able to succesfully use the following attributes to bind to 2 output blob locations:

```
        [Blob("processed/{CorrelationId}", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "OnSchedulingToMMMQueueTriggered:ProcessedPayloadsConnectionString")] out string processedPayload,
        [Blob("success/{CorrelationId}", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "OnSchedulingToMMMQueueTriggered:ProcessedPayloadsConnectionString")] out string success,
```

However, because I am not assigning anything to this value `out string success`, I am getting the following exception:

[image]

**How do I specify output bindings without being forced to assign a value to them? -- In some cases, I don't want any value assigned because I simply do not want to write to that blob.**

My full function below:

```
public static class OnSchedulingToMMMQueueTriggered
{
    [FunctionName("OnSchedulingToMMMQueueTriggered")]
    public static void Run(
        [QueueTrigger("httpqueue", Connection = "OnSchedulingToMMMQueueTriggered:SourceQueueConnection")] Payload myQueueItem,
        [Blob("processed/{CorrelationId}", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "OnSchedulingToMMMQueueTriggered:ProcessedPayloadsConnectionString")] out string processedPayload,
        [Blob("success/{CorrelationId}", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "OnSchedulingToMMMQueueTriggered:ProcessedPayloadsConnectionString")] out string success,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem.Body}");

        processedPayload = "this shoudl be the body of the string";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a specific "out" parameter, it's going to require it.  If the output is conditional, consider just creating a BlobContainer binding and only use it if you need it.  This will require you to create the blob yourself using GetBlockBlobReference, but it's only a little extra code to get around the issue.  I haven't had a chance to test this code below, so you may need to tweak it slightly.

```
public static class OnSchedulingToMMMQueueTriggered
{
    [FunctionName("OnSchedulingToMMMQueueTriggered")]
    public static void Run(
        [QueueTrigger("httpqueue", Connection = "OnSchedulingToMMMQueueTriggered:SourceQueueConnection")] Payload myQueueItem,
        [Blob("processed/{CorrelationId}", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "OnSchedulingToMMMQueueTriggered:ProcessedPayloadsConnectionString")] out string processedPayload,
        [Blob("success", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "OnSchedulingToMMMQueueTriggered:ProcessedPayloadsConnectionString"))] CloudBlobContainer outputSuccessContainer,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem.Body}");

        processedPayload = "this shoudl be the body of the string";

        if (outputNeeded) {
            var blockBlob = outputSuccessContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(CorrelationId + ".txt");
            await blockBlob.UploadText(processedPayload);
            blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "text/plain";
            blockBlob.SetProperties();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: im guessing that i would need to execute `outputSuccessContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();`  first before running the `UploadTextAsync()`?

Comment: Yes, if you cannot be sure that the container you are referencing already exists, then it would be wise to call `await outputSuccessContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();`